# Android Connection TimeOut exception

Tags: android, web-services, http, timeout

Below is the code for which i am getting exception(Time out) please provide any solution or tutorial for the same. Using on 4.0.4 api level device

```
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

 List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();

> param has some values and a string of bitmap.

 HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

StringBuilder receivedData = new StringBuilder();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

String line = null;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
{

receivedData.append(line);

}
```

Comment: Use AsyncTask and do all process in background

Comment: @zala janaksinh : It does not works sir for me ...

Comment: Start Googling and search about bgprocee example it use it`s also wotk dear.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
        TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand what is connectiontimeoutexception:

A timeout while connecting to an HTTP server or waiting for an available connection from an HttpConnectionManager.

So this means your device's internet is unable to make a connection with the HTTP server and the request timeouts. You could do the following two things to avoid this situation:

1. Check for an active internet connection before making an HTTP call using the following method:

   ```
   public static Boolean checkActiveInternet(Context activity) {
   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
       if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
           return true;
       } else if (netInfo != null&& (netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED|| netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTING|| netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.SUSPENDED || netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.UNKNOWN)) {
           return false;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   ```

   }
2. Set a larger timeout to your HTTP request as follows:

   public static String connect(String url) throws IOException {

   ```
   HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
   HttpResponse response;
   HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
   int timeoutConnection = 60 * 1000;
   HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
   int timeoutSocket = 60 * 1000;

   HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
   try {

       response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
       if (entity != null) {
           InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
           result = convertStreamToString(instream);
           // instream.close();
       }
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       Utilities.showDLog("connect", "ClientProtocolException:-" + e);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       Utilities.showDLog("connect", "IOException:-" + e);
   }
   return result;
   ```

   }